# How to hide month entry with unsrtnat bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Entries in my .bib file have a field in the `date={year--month--day}` format and in the bibliography it prints: *April 1999* for instance. I want it to be simply *1999*.

How can you do it with the `unsrtnat` bibliography style?

I tried to find the entry in the file `unsrtnat.bst` but changing the `format.date` function didn't work either. Do You have an idea?

edit: changed the `format.date` fucntion from:

```
FUNCTION {format.date} { year duplicate$ empty$ { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ pop$ "" } 'skip$ if$ month empty$ 'skip$ { month " " * swap$ * } if$ extra.label * }
```

to:

```
FUNCTION {format.date} { year duplicate$ empty$ { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ pop$ "" } 'skip$ if$ month empty$ 'skip$ { } if$ extra.label * }
```

but it didnt work

Comment: Sorry, `natbib`? Your question seems to be about `biblatex`?

Comment: Sorry, should have read more carefully. Does `natbib` really support the date field? If so, don't use `--` to separate year, month and day,

Comment: Please confirm that you're using the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. As @Johannes_B already commented, the `unsrtnat` style isn't programmed to recognize, let alone process, a field named `date`; it does, however, recognize fields named `year` and `month`.

Comment: I export the bib file from zotero and i do not want to change the entries manually

Comment: yeah i use unsrtnat. But is reads the month from the date entry so it seems so work?

Comment: No, it does not. `unsrtnat` reads the month-related information from the field named `month`; it doesn't even process anything in the `date` field (if present). Please advise how you've tried to modify the function `format.date`.

Comment: FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  extra.label *
}

to:

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { 
    }
  if$
  extra.label *
}

Comment: Silly question, but why don't you just rename all date keys in the bib file to say optdate, then they will be completely ignored.

Comment: @daleif - `unsrtnat` doesn't recognize fields named `date` to begin with; renaming them to `xoptdate` thus won't have any effect.

Comment: @Mico Or rename month other what ever is providing the information, often a lot faster than trying to modify a bst

Comment: @daleif - The OP doesn't seem to be familiar with how Zotero might be programmed to suppress outputting the `month` field to a bib file. At any rate, as my answer shows, it's not that difficult to edit the bst file to achieve the desired result. :-)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to clarify that the issue is not with the `natbib` package but with the `unsrtnat` bibliography style.

Comment: @ Mico thank for the effort i will try to do it myself next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To modify the `unsrtnat` bibliography style so that month-related information is ignored, I suggest you take the following steps:

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution and make a copy of this file. Name the copy, say, `unsrtnat-nomonth.bst`. (Do not edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open `unsrtnat-nomonth.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use to modify your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the function `format.date`. (It should start around line 417 of the file.) It should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.date}
  { year duplicate$ empty$
      { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
         pop$ "" }
      'skip$
    if$
    month empty$
      'skip$
      { month
        " " * swap$ *
      }
    if$
    extra.label *
  }
  ```
- Delete the lines from `month empty$` to the second `if$`. The modified function should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.date}
  { year duplicate$ empty$
      { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
         pop$ "" }
      'skip$
    if$
    extra.label *
  }
  ```
- Save the file `unsrtnat-nomonth.bst` either to the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-nomonth}`. Then, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE (with `unsrtnat-nomonth.bst` set up as described in the preceding material)

[image]

If `unsrtnat` were in use instead of `unsrtnat-nomonth`, one would get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{xyz,
  author  = "X",
  title   = "Y",
  journal = "Z",
  year    = 3001,
  month   = "January",
  date    = "11-11-3001",
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-nomonth}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did this before but now the year is also missing!

Comment: @velocity911 - Please check how you've edited your code. Does the blg file report any errors? I've posted an addendum with an MWE that shows the outputs created by both `unsrtnat-nomonth` and `unsrtnat`. There seems to be no problem with showing the contents of the `year` field.

Comment: i have only date, no month try. Could that cause the problem? in your NWE you have a month field .

Comment: @velocity911 - If your entry has no `month` field to begin with, the `unsrtnat` bibliography style won't show any month-related information either. It will certainly not "borrow" month-related information from the field named `date`. Give it a try: Do recompile the MWE shown above with the `month` field deleted (or renamed) and the `date` field intact. (Remember to always run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more* to fully propagate all changes.)

Comment: your instruction was very usefull! it worked now! exactly as you said